# Workaround the lack of 'new(parameters)' in generic in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I found two ways to workaround the lack of 'new(parameters)' in generics but I'm wondering if there's a better solution for that situation.

I require a method in Earth that creates any Fruit using the Dna as parameter in ctor. I have lots of fruits.

Using Activator (or any similar form) has the disadvantage that breaks if the derived class has not the corret ctor or are abstract.

```
public class Earth
{
    public Earth()
    {
        var dna = new Dna();
        var orange = GetFruit<Orange>(dna);
    }

    private static T GetFruit<T>(Dna dna) where T : Fruit
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), dna);
    }
}

public abstract class Fruit
{
    public Fruit(Dna dna)
    {

    }
}

public class Orange : Fruit
{
    public Orange(Dna dna)
        : base(dna)
    {

    }
}

public class Dna
{

}
```

Using a parameterless ctor has the disadvantage that the mandatory Dna becomes optional. The same for a 'Initialize(Dna dna)' method.

```
public class Earth
{
    public Earth()
    {
        var dna = new Dna();
        var orange = GetFruit<Orange>(dna);
    }

    private static T GetFruit<T>(Dna dna) where T : Fruit, new()
    {
        return new T() { Dna = dna };
    }
}

public abstract class Fruit
{
    public Dna Dna { get; set; }
}

public class Orange : Fruit
{

}

public class Dna
{

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to add another parameter: a `Func<Dna, T>`:

```
private static T GetFruit<T>(Dna dna, Func<Dna, T> ctor) where T : Fruit
{
    // I assume your real code does more here?
    return ctor(dna);
}
```

Then you can use:

```
var orange = GetFruit(dna, x => new Orange(x));
```

Note that that also means you don't need to specify the type argument explicitly. The downside is that if you're going to call this from *another* generic method, you'd need to pass the construction delegate throughout the stack :(

Comment: The real code is more complex as you pointed and your solution works very well as it avoid the code smell of the Activator.